# Why both infima are in fact minima?

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, calculus-of-variations, variational-analysis

Let $L:\mathbb{T}^d\times\mathbb{R}^d\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be a Lagrangian over the $d$-dimentional standard torus times $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $\alpha >0$, the **infinite horizon optimal control problem** consist in minimizing
$$
u_{\alpha}(x) = \inf_{\textbf{x}:\textbf{x}(0)=x}\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{\alpha s}L(\textbf{x},\dot{\textbf{x}})\text{ d} s,
$$
amang all globaly Lipschitz trajectories $\mathbf{x}$ with initial condition $\mathbf{x}(0)=x$. Let $T \in \mathbb{R}$, the **initial value problem**, consist in minimizing 
$$
V(x,t) = \inf_{\textbf{x}:\textbf{x}(t)=x}\int_{-T}^{t}L(\textbf{x},\dot{\textbf{x}}) \text{ d} s + \psi(\textbf{x}(-T)),
$$ 
for $t\geq -T$, amang all globaly Lipschitz trajectories $\mathbf{x}$ with initial condition $\mathbf{x}(t)=x$.

This functions satisfies the **dynamic programming principle**, that is, for any $T>0$,

$$
u_{\alpha}(x) = \inf_{\textbf{x}:\textbf{x}(0)=x} \left( \int_{-T}^{0}e^{\alpha s}L(\textbf{x},\dot{\textbf{x}}) \text{ d} s + e^{-\alpha T} u_{\alpha}(\textbf{x}(-T))\right).
$$
Similarly:
$$
V(x,t) = \inf_{\textbf{x}:\textbf{x}(t)=x} \left( \int_{-\tilde{t}}^{t}L(\textbf{x},\dot{\textbf{x}}) \text{ d} s + V(\textbf{x}(-\tilde{t}),-\tilde{t})\right),
$$
for all $-T\leq -\tilde{t} \leq t.$

I need to prove that **both infima are in fact minima**, and I am trying to use the **compactness** of the torus and some **argument of calculus of variation**, but I don't achieve anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is enough to note that the functions $u_{\alpha}$ and $V$ are continuous and then use the extreme value theorem thanks to the compactness of the torus.